# Stripe Elements JS redirect user

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm following the guide on Stripes docs https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price

Everything works, I just cannot work out how to actually redirect the user from the JS

```
function onSubscriptionComplete(result) {
  // Payment was successful.
  if (result.subscription.status === 'active') {
     console.log('redirect');
 
      location.href = 'https://google.com';
  }
}
```

Here the console is logging redirect but the user is not redirected. What is the best way to redirect the user after confirming the payment?

Comment: maybe try setting `window.location.href` as on the demo projects [does](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/54d1d082/per-seat-subscriptions/client/script.js#L737-L738) ? It should be the same, but not entirely sure why this doesn't work as-is.

Comment: I've can't believe it was something so simple. Thank you!